# jQuery: Possibility to refactor different events with identical action

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, refactoring

Is it possible to refactor the following coffeescript further in a way so that `disableFilterButton()` could be called only once?

```
$("#user_department, #user_position").change ->
  disableFilterButton()

$("#user_email, #employee_id").click ->
  disableFilterButton()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) menthod instead `change`, `click`:

```
$("#user_department, #user_position").one 'change', ->
  disableFilterButton()

$("#user_email, #employee_id").one 'click', ->
  disableFilterButton()
```